# How to add the Data.HashMap Hashable type constraint?

Tags: haskell, hashmap, type-constraints

I've got this working function that counts the occurrences of each element in a list and constructs a map out of it:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M

counter :: [Int] -> M.HashMap Int Int
counter = foldr (\x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1) mempty
```

Now I want to generalise this to:

```
counter :: (Eq k) => [k] -> M.HashMap k Int
counter = foldr (\x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1) mempty
```

but apparently, I also need the `Hashable k` type constraint since `M.insertWith` requires it. I've tried multiple ways of adding the constraint but failed miserably in all attempts<sup>1</sup>.

Is there a fancy way to add the type constraint or perhaps a language pragma that might help me out?

---

Full error message:

```
    • Could not deduce (hashable-1.3.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable
                          k)
        arising from a use of ‘M.insertWith’
      from the context: Eq k
        bound by the type signature for:
                   counter :: forall k. Eq k => [k] -> M.HashMap k Int
        at <interactive>:5:1-43
      Possible fix:
        add (hashable-1.3.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable
               k) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            counter :: forall k. Eq k => [k] -> M.HashMap k Int
    • In the expression: M.insertWith (+) x 1
      In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(\ x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1)’
      In the expression: foldr (\ x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1) mempty
```

<sup>1: Adding `hashable-1.3.1.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable k` (as suggested by the error), `Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable k`, or `M.Hashable k` to the type constraint doesn't work. Importing Data.Hashable.Class doesn't work since it's a hidden module.</sup>

Comment: Usually when GHC prints the package *version* in the error it's a real good sign you've fubar'd your package database. I would bet if you `ghc-pkg list hashable` you'll see multiple versions listed. Consider using `ghc-pkg hide` on all but one of them. ...but the real story is even more complicated than that, as you may already have some packages built against the versions you hide. It's pretty complicated to get this stuff right manually, which is why cabal and stack exist in the first place.

Comment: @DanielWagner Haha, my package database definitely has some issues. When installing packages through cabal, it often "Could not resolve dependencies" and always pointed to the `directory` and `process` packages (which were indirectly(?) installed). Also, `ghc-pkg list hashable` returns no packages; and when I try to cabal install it, it couldn't resolve against `directory`. ‍♂️ Normally I would edit the config file directly (also one time I tried reinstalling ghc to fix a similar problem ‍♂️), but thanks to the wonderful world of stack, I don't need to do this anymore. :)

Comment: @TrebledJ: I think that is the main reason to work with haskell-stack/cabal: you can make virtual environments like in Python where for a specific project you load specific packages, and this has no effect on other projects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem virtual environments? I never saw it that way. In Stack you have very concrete environments with fixed package-version combination in a fixed location. With Cabal, you have a single database from which it picks a dependency graph of suitable versions. Sometimes you get those weird version conflicts that shouldn't be, but at least _when it works_ it's always quite clear how. [Whereas in Python...](https://xkcd.com/1987/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You import it from the `Data.Hashable` module, so:

```
import Data.Hashable(Hashable)

counter :: (Hashable k, Eq k) => [k] -> M.HashMap k Int
counter = foldr (\x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1) mempty
```

You likely do not expose the `hashable` package at the moment, in your .cabal file you can list this under the dependencies:

```
-- …
executable …
  -- …
  build-depends:
      base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , hashable >=1.0
    -- …
  -- …
```

Comment: Aww man, I need to use cabal now >.<. I've had a deep-rooted fear of stack and cabal ever since I first touched them. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @TrebledJ: well the only thing you need to do is expose the package to the haskell file(s). It is however not entirely clear to me how you are building your program.

Comment: I've mostly been just using `runhaskell` or `ghc -O3 ...`. I'm guessing there's a flag to expose packages, but I should probably learn to use cabal anyways.

Comment: @TrebledJ: imho haskell-stack is probably more convenient. With `ghc` you can work with `ghc -package package1 -package package2 ...`

Comment: `ghc -package hashable Main.hs` didn't work... same error as in the question. :/ But I ended up getting stack to work, so it's all good now.